# How do I Paginate my CMS

Tags: php, mysql

I've been following the Build a CMS in an Afternoon tutorial at http://www.elated.com/articles/cms-in-an-afternoon-php-mysql/ .

The CMS works great but the only thing it's lacking is pagination. The article archive displays the list of all of the articles that are in the database, but I want to be able to separate these into pages. I've attempted it a few times but can never seem to get it to work. Clicking on a next page link usually brings me back to the homepage.

I will apreciate your help

Code:

> config.php
>
> ```
> <?php ini_set( "display_errors", true ); 
> date_default_timezone_set("europe/lisbon" );  
> define( "DB_DSN", "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cms" ); 
> define( "DB_USERNAME", "username" );
> define( "DB_PASSWORD", "password" );
> define( "CLASS_PATH", "classes" ); 
> define( "TEMPLATE_PATH", "templates" ); 
> define( "HOMEPAGE_NUM_ARTICLES", 5 ); 
> define( "ADMIN_USERNAME", "admin" ); 
> define( "ADMIN_PASSWORD", "mypass" );
> require( CLASS_PATH . "/Article.php" );   
>
> function handleException( $exception ) {   
> echo "Sorry, a problem occurred. Please try later."; 
> error_log( $exception->getMessage() ); }   
>
> set_exception_handler( 'handleException' ); ?>
> ```

archive.php

```
<?php include "templates/include/header.php" ?>
 
      <h1>Article Archive</h1>
 
      <ul id="headlines" class="archive">
 
<?php foreach ( $results['articles'] as $article ) { ?>
 
        <li>
          <h2>
            <span class="pubDate"><?php echo date('j F Y', $article->publicationDate)?></span><a href=".?action=viewArticle&amp;articleId=<?php echo $article->id?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $article->title )?></a>
          </h2>
          <p class="summary"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $article->summary )?></p>
        </li>
 
<?php } ?>
 
      </ul>
 
      <p><?php echo $results['totalRows']?> article<?php echo ( $results['totalRows'] != 1 ) ? 's' : '' ?> in total.</p>
 
      <p><a href="./">Return to Homepage</a></p>
 
<?php include "templates/include/footer.php" ?>
```

> article.php

```
<?php
 
/**
 * Class to handle articles
 */
 
class Article
{
  public $id = null;

  public $publicationDate = null;
 
  public $title = null;

  public $summary = null;
 
  public $content = null;
 
 
  public function __construct( $data=array() ) {
    if ( isset( $data['id'] ) ) $this->id = (int) $data['id'];
    if ( isset( $data['publicationDate'] ) ) $this->publicationDate = (int) $data['publicationDate'];
    if ( isset( $data['title'] ) ) $this->title = preg_replace ( "/[^\.\,\-\_\'\"\@\?\!\:\$ a-zA-Z0-9()]/", "", $data['title'] );
    if ( isset( $data['summary'] ) ) $this->summary = preg_replace ( "/[^\.\,\-\_\'\"\@\?\!\:\$ a-zA-Z0-9()]/", "", $data['summary'] );
    if ( isset( $data['content'] ) ) $this->content = $data['content'];
  }
 
 
  public function storeFormValues ( $params ) {
 
    // Store all the parameters
    $this->__construct( $params );
 
    // Parse and store the publication date
    if ( isset($params['publicationDate']) ) {
      $publicationDate = explode ( '-', $params['publicationDate'] );
 
      if ( count($publicationDate) == 3 ) {
        list ( $y, $m, $d ) = $publicationDate;
        $this->publicationDate = mktime ( 0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y );
      }
    }
  }
 
 
  public static function getById( $id ) {
    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $sql = "SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS publicationDate FROM articles WHERE id = :id";
    $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $st->bindValue( ":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->execute();
    $row = $st->fetch();
    $conn = null;
    if ( $row ) return new Article( $row );
  }
 
 
  public static function getList( $numRows=1000000, $order="publicationDate DESC" ) {
    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS publicationDate FROM articles
            ORDER BY " . mysql_escape_string($order) . " LIMIT :numRows";
 
    $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $st->bindValue( ":numRows", $numRows, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->execute();
    $list = array();
 
    while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
      $article = new Article( $row );
      $list[] = $article;
    }
 
    // Now get the total number of articles that matched the criteria
    $sql = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS totalRows";
    $totalRows = $conn->query( $sql )->fetch();
    $conn = null;
    return ( array ( "results" => $list, "totalRows" => $totalRows[0] ) );
  }
 
 
?>
```

Comment: Your LIMIT (inside the getList function) has to set two parameters, like ( http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx ). Then, you can pass the number of rows per page  with your $numRows variable. Don't forget to create the link "<< back" and "next >>" (<a href/>) sending the next page via $_GET

Comment: Thanks Guilherme. Can you point an example please!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your code to $_GET the page number and use limit and offset in the query

you can see this example

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_paging_php.htm