# PHP MYSQL Pagination CMS

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

(this code was updated after some answer from another topic: [How do I Paginate my CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29818240/how-do-i-paginate-my-cmsp))

I've been following the Build a CMS in an Afternoon tutorial at http://www.elated.com/articles/cms-in-an-afternoon-php-mysql/ .

The CMS works great but the only thing it's lacking is pagination. The article archive displays the list of all of the articles that are in the database, but I want to be able to separate these into pages. I've attempted it a few times but can never seem to get it to work. Clicking on a next page link usually brings me back to the homepage.

I will apreciate your help

The code:

ARTICLE

```
 public static function getList( $numRows=130, $order="publicationDate DESC" ) {
        $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $offset = ($_GET['page'] - 1) * $numRows;
    $rowCount = 20;

    $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS publicationDate FROM articles
            ORDER BY " . mysql_escape_string($order) . " LIMIT :offset, :rowCount";

     $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
     $st->bindValue( ":offset", $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT );
     $st->bindValue( ":rowCount", $rowCount, PDO::PARAM_INT );;
        $st->execute();
        $list = array();

        while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
          $article = new Article( $row );
          $list[] = $article;
        }

        // Now get the total number of articles that matched the criteria
        $sql = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS totalRows";
        $totalRows = $conn->query( $sql )->fetch();
        $conn = null;
        return ( array ( "results" => $list, "totalRows" => $totalRows[0] ) );
      }


             $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );  $st->bindValue( ":offset", $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT );  $st->bindValue( ":rowCount", $rowCount, PDO::PARAM_INT );;
                $st->execute();
                $list = array();

                while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
                  $article = new Article( $row );
                  $list[] = $article;
                }

                // Now get the total number of articles that matched the criteria
                $sql = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS totalRows";
                $totalRows = $conn->query( $sql )->fetch();
                $conn = null;
                return ( array ( "results" => $list, "totalRows" => $totalRows[0] ) );   }
```

ARQUIVE

```
 <ul class="noticias_archive">

<?php foreach ( $results['articles'] as $article ) { ?>

        <li>
                        <div class="noticias_archive col-4">

            <?php if ( $imagePath = $article->getImagePath( IMG_TYPE_THUMB ) ) { ?>
              <a href=".?action=viewArticle&amp;articleId=<?php echo $article->id?>"><img class="articleImageThumb" src="<?php echo $imagePath?>" alt="Article Thumbnail" /></a>
            <?php } ?></div>


                         <div class="noticias_archive col-4">


          <h3 class="top">
           <a href=".?action=viewArticle&amp;articleId=<?php echo $article->id?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $article->title )?></a>
          </h3>
         <p>
          <?php echo htmlspecialchars( $article->summary )?><br><br><?php echo date('j F Y', $article->publicationDate)?></p>


         </div>

        </li>

<?php } ?> 

      </ul>

          </div>

     <p>


     <?php  
     if ( isset( $_GET['page'] ) ){
    echo sprintf('<p> <a href="./?action=noticias?page=%d"> << Back </a> </p>', $_GET['page'] - 1);
echo sprintf('<p> <a href="./?action=noticias?page=%d"> Next >> </a> </p>', $_GET['page'] + 1);}?> in total.</p>

      <p><a href="./">Return to Homepage</a></p>
```

INDEX

```
require( "config.php" );
$action = isset( $_GET['action'] ) ? $_GET['action'] : "";

switch ( $action ) {
  case 'noticias':
    noticias();
    break;
  case 'viewArticle':
    viewArticle();
    break;
    default:
    homepage();
}

function noticias() {
  $results = array();
  $data = Article::getList();
  $results['articles'] = $data['results'];
  $results['totalRows'] = $data['totalRows'];
  $results['pageTitle'] = "Article Archive | teste";
  require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/archive.php" );
}

function viewArticle() {
  if ( !isset($_GET["articleId"]) || !$_GET["articleId"] ) {
    homepage();
    return;
  }

  $results = array();
  $results['article'] = Article::getById( (int)$_GET["articleId"] );
  $results['pageTitle'] = $results['article']->title . " | teste2";
  require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/viewArticle.php" );
}

function homepage() {
  $results = array();
  $data = Article::getList( HOMEPAGE_NUM_ARTICLES );
  $results['articles'] = $data['results'];
  $results['totalRows'] = $data['totalRows'];
  $results['pageTitle'] = "FPT - teste3";
  require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/homepage.php" );
}
```

Comment: Please don’t create duplicate questions. You have already asked this question (with no accepted answers) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29818240/how-do-i-paginate-my-cms

Comment: Please read careful my post. The answers where valid in the another post, but i messed up after updating the code, so i was advised to create this post with the updated code. thanks

Comment: You don’t need to create two separate questions about the same issue. These are both related to adding pagination to a custom PHP-based CMS.